# Registering a User to .Net Core Project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, relational-database

I am writing a .Net Core project in which I am trying to implement a user registration process. I've used the "basic" template provided by Microsoft as I am writing in Visual Studio 2017.

I have stumpled into problem with how the user is registered. I have created a pretty substantial form with the information I require to complete a registration:

## RegisterViewModel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
    public bool Manager { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date_Of_Birth { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I have left out some of the unimportant lines from the above, as that is not a part of my problem. The part of displaying my form works as intended but when I try to run my `[HttpPost]` part I stumble into problems.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //do something else here if user was created.
        }
    }
}
```

My database is a relational database (has foreign keys) which means that when I try to add a `User` through this process and the user doesn't have a `CustomerID` (added or it isn't set) the display of the "User" index doesn't work (breaks).

[image]

In the register code above a user is created in my database however none of the fields that was filled from my form are input to my database. And worst of all the customer ID (which is a foreign key) doesn't get inserted, even though it resides in the model.

How do I pass these variables that I NEED from this register method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

It seems that Visual Studio was so kind to supply me with an `ApplicationUser.cs` class that just required modification.

The following line was found in my code posted above:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

I found the `ApplicationUser` class and modified it to contain my model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int CustomerID { get; internal set; }
    public string FirstName { get; internal set; }
    public string LastName { get; internal set; }
    public string FullName { get; internal set; }
    public string Gender { get; internal set; }
    public string CName { get; internal set; }
    public DateTime CDate { get; internal set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; internal set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; internal set; }
    public string Status { get; internal set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; internal set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; internal set; }
    public string Contact1 { get; internal set; }
    public string Contact2 { get; internal set; }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else out there!